# How to do unit test (check if data were written) on appengine with entities stored inside XG transaction

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine, transactions

I am making unit tests for GAE. Service method I am testing is using transaction and as actions inside that transaction spans over more entity groups I need to use "withXG". In order to be able to test it, I need to setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100). Then I do not know how to check data writen inside this method as it is kept unapplied. I feel deadlocked?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? If you are only testing that the data are written, then why do want to set `unapplied job percentage` to 100?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, solution found .. instead of setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(0) - gives IllegalArgumen... I HAVE TO USE setApplyAllHighRepJobPolicy.